# Background buttons are displayed on top of a toggle button

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have this problem:[image]

As you can see that my popup is not hiding the two buttons which are displayed on the page on IE9 but works fine on Mozilla. I have this on my CSS styles on that toggle button:

```
    .Test.toggle-button {
    background-image: url("../../../images/expand16.gif");
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 20%;
}
```

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
 <div class="pay-instruction-labels">
    <div class="pay-instruction-title">
        Payment Instructions:
    </div>
    <span class="current-details toggle-button">Current</span>
    <span class="prior-years-details toggle-button">Prior Years</span>
    <div class="pay-instruction-fields">
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Edit your question and show us the HTML which you use to add the toggle buttons. Which HTML element do you use?

Comment: Did that, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a z-index issue. Can you try giving your popup container element `position:relative` and a `z-index:9999` ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a native rendering issue: IE9 uses Windows buttons; these are rendered by Windows outside of the normal HTML renderer.

Try to replace the buttons with something that just looks like a button (for example a link that is styled with an image).

Answer (score 0):

It was a position: relative fault. Fixed it, it worked. Thanks everyone :)